# a problem about possible generating series

Tags: nt.number-theory, co.combinatorics

I have met the following problem in my research, which seems to be a purely combinatorics problem, as a non-specialist in the area I hope to getting help from you:

Suppose $g(z)$ is a formal power series in $z$ which is of the form as $$\prod_{n}(1-z^n)^{-n}$$

Let $\lambda=(j^{a_j})\vdash n$ be a partition of $n$, one write $N(\lambda)$ for the set of $j$ such that $a_j\neq 0$. For a $j\in N(\lambda)$, define $$S_j(\lambda)=\sum_{i\in N(\lambda)}a_i \min\{i,j \}$$
Write $[z^n]$ for the operation of taking coefficient of $z^n$, I am wondering if is it possible to have a generating series for $N_n$ or $n^2 N_n$   where $N_n$ is defined as following:
  $$ N_n=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{\lambda\vdash n}\frac{|N(\lambda)|}{\sum_j a_j}\prod_{j\in N(\lambda)}[z^{a_j}]g(z)^{S_j(\lambda)}  $$

An observation is that for each $n$, the definition of $N_n$ involves only a finite partial product of $g(z)$.

Any help, a reference for a question similar or some observations, is welcome! Thanks a lot!

P.S.
In fact I believe that the number
$$\sum_{l|n}\frac{\mu(l)}{l^2}N_{\frac{n}{l}}$$
is always an integer where $\mu(.)$ is the Mobiüs function. Results in this direction are also desired.

Comment: Can you tell the story behind the numbers $ N_n $? Maybe this is already known, but maybe worth mentioning that $g(z)$ is inverse g.f. for plane partitions given by MacMahon formula. I cannot understand what you mean by "finite partial product". Thanks for clarifications.

Comment: @SergeyDovgal Thank you for mentioning this, I have no idea about what combinatorics meaning should be about these function... In fact, it's a much more complicated function than $g(z)$ that was considered which comes from automorphic forms... The function I wrote is a special case for my consideration, in fact it's the inverse of $g(z)$ for this special case, sorry for my fault.The most difficult thing for me is on how to deal with $S_j(\lambda)$ as I have never seen this kind of number in combinatorics.